# Closure call with mismatched arguments

Tags: flutter, dart, closures

hey guys I'm struggling with this error. I've tried some things until I got the below code but the error still here. Just to you know, I'm new to Flutter. I've started learning it about one month ago and this is my first real project with it.

This is the log:

```
E/flutter ( 3213): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Closure call with mismatched arguments: function '_GameChoosingOrTypingState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>'
E/flutter ( 3213): Receiver: Closure: () => Null
E/flutter ( 3213): Tried calling: _GameChoosingOrTypingState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>(Instance of 'StatefulElement')
E/flutter ( 3213): Found: _GameChoosingOrTypingState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>() => Null
E/flutter ( 3213): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter ( 3213): #1      _CustomProgressIndicatorState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:fun_math/screens/games/widgets/custom_progress_indicator.dart:30:26)
E/flutter ( 3213): #2      new Future.delayed.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:318:39)
E/flutter ( 3213): #3      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1180:38)
E/flutter ( 3213): #4      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter ( 3213): #5      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
E/flutter ( 3213): #6      _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
E/flutter ( 3213): #7      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
E/flutter ( 3213): #8      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter ( 3213): #9      _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1003:23)
E/flutter ( 3213): #10     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:23:15)
E/flutter ( 3213): #11     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:398:19)
E/flutter ( 3213): #12     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)
E/flutter ( 3213): #13     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
E/flutter ( 3213): `
```

Here is my code:

```
class CustomProgressIndicator extends StatefulWidget {
  final double value;
  final Function onFinish;

  CustomProgressIndicator({
    @required this.onFinish,
    this.value
  });

  @override
  _CustomProgressIndicatorState createState() => _CustomProgressIndicatorState();
}

class _CustomProgressIndicatorState extends State<CustomProgressIndicator> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final maxWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    bool isWaitingOnFinish = false;

    //Called onFinish after progress is complete
    // and build animation is complete
    if (widget.value == 1) {
      if (!isWaitingOnFinish) {
        isWaitingOnFinish = true;
        Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
          widget.onFinish(context);
        });
      }
    }

    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: MyColors.secondaryColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topRight: Radius.circular(100),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(100))
        ),
      width: maxWidth * ((widget.value >= 0) ? widget.value : 0),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is where I call the widget that throws the exception:

```
class GameChoosingOrTyping extends StatefulWidget {
  _GameChoosingOrTypingState createState() => _GameChoosingOrTypingState();
}

class _GameChoosingOrTypingState extends State<GameChoosingOrTyping> {
  final isTimer = SessionData.gameStyle == GameStyle.timer;
  final isChoosing = SessionData.gameType == GameType.choosing;
  var subject;
  final durationSeconds = SessionData.gameDuration;
  final textQuestion = ValueNotifier<String>('');
  final questionIndexNotifier = ValueNotifier<int>(-1);
  var question;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textQuestion.dispose();
    questionIndexNotifier.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (subject == null)
      switch(SessionData.subject) {
        case Subject.addition:
          subject = ChoosingOrTypingAdditionSubject();
          break;

        case Subject.subtraction:
          subject = ChoosingOrTypingSubtractionSubject();
          break;

        case Subject.multiplication:
          subject = ChoosingOrTypingMultiplicationSubject();
          break;

        case Subject.division:
          subject = ChoosingOrTypingDivisionSubject();
          break;
      }


    loadNewQuestion();

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: isTimer ? CountdownTimer(
                  onFinish: onFinish,
                  duration: Duration(seconds: durationSeconds),) :
                    ValueListenableBuilder(
                      valueListenable: questionIndexNotifier,
                      builder: (context, value, child) =>
                          CustomProgressIndicator(
                            value: value / SessionData.questionsQuantity,
                            onFinish: onFinish,
                          ),
                    ),
          ),
          ),

          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Center(
                child: ValueListenableBuilder(
                  valueListenable: textQuestion,
                  builder: (context, value, child) => Text(
                    value,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontSize: 30,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          Expanded(
            flex: 7,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
              color: Colors.white,
              child: isChoosing ?
              ValueListenableBuilder(
                valueListenable: textQuestion,
                builder: (context, value, child) => GameButtonsChoose(
                  values: question.choices,
                  onSelected: onSelectedChoice,
                ),
              ) :
              GameKeyboard(
                onInputUpdate: onInputUpdate,
                onSendInput: onSelectedChoice,
              )
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void onInputUpdate(input) {
    textQuestion.value = question.question.replaceAll('?', input);
  }

  void onFinish(BuildContext context) {
    if (Navigator.of(context) != null)
      dev.log('onFinish() called');
      Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  void onSelectedChoice(choice) {
      dev.log('The selected choice is ' +  choice +
      ' and the answer is ' + (question.answer == int.parse(choice) ?
      'correct.' : 'wrong.' + " " + question.answer.toString()));
      loadNewQuestion();
  }

  void loadNewQuestion() {
    dev.log('loadNewQuestion() called');
    questionIndexNotifier.value++;
    question = subject.nextQuestion();
    textQuestion.value = question.question;
    dev.log('question : ${question.question}');
  }
}
```

I hope anyone can help me?